Assigning column from different data frame - role of index
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['b', 'b', 'b']})
df_2.index = [4,5,6]

df_1['col2'] = df_2.col1

I expect a simple copy in the above example, but 'col2' in df_1 is all NAs. I find it strange. What is the rational for this choice? Similar example works differently in R.

The rationale is to keep the data aligned. The same way columns are aligned when you perform an operation.
This enables to perform complex operations without having to worry about the order of the rows/columns like you would with numpy:
A = pd.DataFrame({'blue': [1, 2], 'green': [3, 4]}, index=['circle', 'square'])
B = pd.DataFrame({'green': [10, 20], 'blue': [30, 40]}, index=['square', 'circle'])

A+B

        blue  green
circle    41     23
square    32     14

Or to handle missing data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']})
df['col2'] = pd.Series(['b1', 'b3'], index=[0, 2])

print(df)

  col1 col2
0   a1   b1
1   a2  NaN
2   a3   b3

Or to perform broadcasting:
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], [1, 2]],
                                  names=['letter', 'number'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=idx1)

idx2 = pd.Index([1, 2], name='number')
df['col2'] = df['col1'] * pd.Series([1, 10], index=idx2)

print(df)

               col1  col2
letter number            
a      1          1     1
       2          2    20
b      1          3     3
       2          4    40

If you want to avoid this you can convert to array:
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']})
df_2.index = [2,3,1]

df_1['col2'] = df_2['col1']
df_1['col3'] = df_2['col1'].values # or df_2['col1'].to_numpy()

Output:
  col1 col2 col3
0   a1  NaN   b1
1   a2   b3   b2
2   a3   b1   b3


Thank you, but this is so not intuitive. This is kind different way of thinking of data. SQL and R rely on joins to keep data aligned.

@user1700890 it's a different paradigm. I would say it's rather intuitive, you can rely on the indices for complex operations. Of course it has some pitfalls. I've added a few more examples.
